# Projection exists ⇒ Uniformly convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I know that: Let X be a uniformly convex Banach space, $a\in X$ and $C\subset X$ closed and convex, then there is a unique $b\in C$ with $\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert=\inf_{x\in C}\left\Vert a-x \right\Vert$.

Moreover I know that: let $X$ be a Banach space, such that for every $a\in X$ and $C\subset X$  closed and convex there is at most one $b\in C$ with $\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert=\inf_{x\in C}\left\Vert a-x \right\Vert$. Then $X$ is strictly convex.

So I wonder, if the following statement is true: Let $X$ be a Banach space, such that for every $a\in X$ and $C\subset X$ closed and convex, there is a unique $b\in C$ with $\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert=\inf_{x\in C}\left\Vert a-x \right\Vert$. Then $X$ is uniformly convex.

EDIT: This statement is false, see Hsueh-Yung Lin's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81979/projection-exists-uniformly-convex#comment210420_81979). So I should ask: Let $X$ be a Banach space, such that for every $a\in X$ and $C\subset X$  closed and convex, there is a unique $b\in C$ with $\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert=\inf_{x\in C}\left\Vert a-x \right\Vert$. Then every bounded sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence.

Comment: Well, take a finite-dimensional strictly convex (but not uniformly convex Banach space).  Then compactness will ensure the existence of a point of best approximation.  For an infinite-dimensional example, use a reflexive strictly (but not uniformly) convex space and argue via weak compactness.  I'm not convinced this is a great question for this site: http://math.stackexchange.com/ might be better.

Comment: The following article might help you:

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1941-47-04/S0002-9904-1941-07451-3/S0002-9904-1941-07451-3.pdf

Comment: @Matthew: a compactness argument actually shows that a finite dimensional strictly convex Banach space is uniformly convex.

Comment: @Hsueh-Yung Lin: interesting paper. M. Day provides a example for a reflexive strictly convex space, which is not isomorphic to a uniformly convex space. So we get the unique best approximation, because every bounded sequence admits a weakly-convergent subsequence, so I have to modify my question. 

Is it true, that,
if every closed convex set admits a best approximation, then every bounded sequence admits a weakly-convergent subsequence.


Comment: @Mark: Ah, yes!  Very silly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your modified question has an affirmative answer.  An equivalent form, in view of the Eberlein-Smulian theorem, is whether the Banach space $X$ must be reflexive if every closed bounded non empty set admits best approximations.  If $X$ is not reflexive, then by R. C. James' famous characterization of reflexivity, there is a norm one linear functional $F$ on $X$ s.t. $F$ does not achieve its norm on the closed unit ball $B_X$.  Let $C:= [F=1]\cap 2B_X$. This closed bounded non empty convex set contains no point of minimal norm.